# if statement not looping through all the data?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a CSV data that I am writing in Python. I already completed a Jupyter Notebook as a prototype. It looks like the loop is ending on the first row of data. What is the fix for this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import datetime 


data = pd.read_csv("logrecords.csv")
vehicle = 'NM52'
df = data[data['VEHICLE'] == vehicle]

degree_change = 0.000011 
speed_change = 0 
time_change = datetime.timedelta(seconds=150)

def conditionA(df, degree_change):
    lat = df['lat']
    df['lat_rolled'] = np.roll(lat, 1) 
    df['lat_difference'] = df['lat'] - df['lat_rolled']
    lat_conditionA =  df['lat_difference'] < degree_change
    lon = df['lon']
    df['lon_rolled'] = np.roll(lon, 1)
    df['lon_difference'] = df['lon'] - df['lon_rolled'] 
    lon_conditionA = df['lon_difference'] < degree_change 

    if lat_conditionA + lon_conditionA == True: 
        print(True)
    else: 
        print(False) 


def conditionB(df, speed_change):
    speed = df['speed']
    speed_rolled = np.roll(speed,1)
    df['speed_difference'] = df['speed'] - df['speed_rolled']
    speed_change_conditionB = (df['speed_difference'] == speed_change)

    if speed_change_conditionB == True:
        print(True) 
    else: 
        print(False)


def conditionC(df, time_change):
    time = df['time']
    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
    time_rolled = np.roll(time,1)
    df['time_rolled'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time_rolled)
    df['time_difference'] = df['time'] - df['time_rolled']
    time_conditionC = (df['time_difference'] > time_change)

    if time_conditionC == True:
        print(True) 
    else:
        print(False)


def trip_validation(conditionA, conditionB,conditionC):
    if (conditionA and conditionB and conditionC) == True: 
        print(True)
    else: 
        print(False)

    return;

trip_validation(conditionA, conditionB, conditionC)
```

My only output is False, which is the right answer for the first row of data.

Comment: @Barmar, how does the boolean math apply to this?

Comment: You should be using `and` or `or` when combining `lat_conditionA` and `lon_conditionA`, not `+`.

Comment: @Barmar this worked better! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two large problems.

(1)
Your program doesn't loop through all the data because you have no loop.  You're working with data frame columns as a whole, and then magically expecting them to behave as scalar values in some magic fashion.

I suggest that you work carefully through the tutorials on data frames.  `print` your results after each statement as you go, to make sure that you get what you expect.

(2)
You are not yet comfortable with boolean operations.

The *immediate* problem is your statement:

```
if (conditionA and conditionB and conditionC) == True: 
    print(True)
else: 
    print(False)
```

The three `condition` operands are function objects.  You *never* call the functions, so virtually none of  the prior code is ever executed.  This statement checks to see whether all three objects are defined (i.e. not `None`).  As you*have* defined all three functions nicely, this is `True`, giving you your one line of output.  This has nothing to do with your data frame.

Calling the functions would not solve the problem, as all three functions return the default of `None`, and you'll get a `False` output as a result.  Work through your materials again; you need to `return` the values, not `print` them.

---

The direct way to get the output in your main program would be something like

```
print( conditionA(df, change) and
       conditionB(df, change) and
       conditionC(df, change)   )
```

This is how I can tell you're not comfortable with Booleans.

```
if condition == True:
```

is redundant; `if` automatically checks the truth value.

```
if expr:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

is also redundant.  Simply `print(expr)`, as you would with any other variable.